# How to print range of array in python

Tags: python, image-processing

How to print the range of array in python?

and why when I tried to print the array,

```
ReadImage = cv2.imread(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(ReadImage)
```

it gives me 3 channels

```
 [[ 8  8  8]
  [ 8  8  8]
  [ 8  8  8]
  ..., 
  [ 8  8  8]
  [ 8  8  8]
  [ 8  8  8]]
```

How can I print just print one channel array?

and how to get is the biggest number in the array when there inf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `ReadImage = ReadImage[:, :, X]` where `X` is the channel you want to select.

For your second question, you might want to sort your array and then select the second maximum number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Aref I already tried it but the result just [ ] .